# How to update in entity without updating the file upload field

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file-upload

I would like to ask for help, you see I have an update method that doesn't work when the image upload input is empty. This shouldn't be the case since not fields are updated all the time. I am using Entity framework for my backend.

---

This is the code from the controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ClearanceDB clearanceDB)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(clearanceDB.ImageFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(clearanceDB.ImageFile.FileName);
                fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                clearanceDB.picture = "/Image/" + fileName;
                fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Image/"), fileName);
                clearanceDB.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
                using (ClearanceModels dbModel = new ClearanceModels())
                {
                    dbModel.Entry(clearanceDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    //dbModel.Entry(clearanceDB).Property(p => p.ImageFile).IsModified = false;
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                //if (clearanceDB.ImageFile == null)
                //{
                //    dbModel.Entry(clearanceDB).Property(I => I.ImageFile).IsModified = false;
                //}
                return View();
            }
        }
```

as you can see in the commented sections I tried using the "IsModified" property to prevent the image from uploading but alas it is not working. I also tried checking if the image is null but it's also not working. Since I already tried the "IsModified" property and it is the most recurring solution that I find I don't know what else to try. Other solutions are too complicated I only need for the update to work without uploading a new image. Any help is appreciated thank you.

---

This is the ClearanceDB class Model, the picture is the only field causing this problem so I didn't put the other fields.

```
[Display(Name = "Picture")]
 //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
public string picture { get; set; }

ublic HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
```

---

Code from the view if that helps

```
<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.picture)" height="200" width="250" />
                <input type="file" name="ImageFile" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.picture)">
```

Comment: When upload input is empty - what do you mean? What fields are empty? Maybe you have to show us ClearanceDB  class. What fields are you trying  to update?

Comment: Hello I have included the ClearanceDB class. As for your question it is when the image upload is empty, meaning the update will not work unless a new picture is uploaded. This is not happening to the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and more research I able to fixed the problem. First I remove the try catch to find the root cause, upon removing the try catch it gave a NullReferenceException with this I realized that the clearanceDB.ImageFile is null which is correct because no new image is uploaded however there is no logic with this scenario and therefore the program is posting the null value.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id, ClearanceDB clearanceDB)
        {
            if (clearanceDB.ImageFile == null)
            {
                using (ClearanceModels dbModel = new ClearanceModels())
                {
                    dbModel.Entry(clearanceDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbModel.Entry(clearanceDB).Property(p => p.picture).IsModified = false;
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(clearanceDB.ImageFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(clearanceDB.ImageFile.FileName);
                fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                clearanceDB.picture = "/Image/" + fileName;
                fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Image/"), fileName);
                clearanceDB.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
                using (ClearanceModels dbModel = new ClearanceModels())
                {
                    dbModel.Entry(clearanceDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is the updated Edit function from the Controller I know there are repeated codes in here I will try to improve that for now I am happy to resolve this issue.